# How can I prevent non-numbers being entered into an up/down control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, validation, data-annotations

**EDIT**: *I'm trying to get the built-in "editor" helpers to work properly. I don't want to re-implement those helpers (or the client-side validation that they provide "for free"). I'm looking for a solution that ideally lets me achieve what I want simply by adding some extra data-annotations, or even upgrading some of the standard libraries.*

Suppose I have an entity with an integer field, like this:

```
class Foo
{
    // ...
    public int Price { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Now suppose that in a web form, I use `EditorFor(m => m.Price)`. In current versions of MVC, this will render an `<input type="number">` HTML tag, which on modern browsers will display an up/down control. Good so far.

However, if the user enters "x" into the control and clicks "Submit", then the error message shown seems wrong: "The Price field is required".

*NOTE: this is much worse if the field is nullable - in that case, it silently discards the "x" and treats the field as empty. Yuk!*

If I try to prevent invalid numbers using a `[RegularExpression]` attribute, it doesn't seem to test the regular expression unless the field already contains a valid number(!).

My regular expression is `^\d*\.?\d*$` which does not allow a minus sign. No error is shown for "x" but an error is shown for "-1".

Is there any way to improve this (especially in the case of nullable fields)?

Answer (score 0):

In my controller i use this

```
[...]
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Price))
{
     ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Insert a value");
     return View(model);
}
if (Regex.Matches(model.Price , @"^[a-zA-Z]+$").Count > 0)
{
     ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Non numeric value");
     return View(model);
}
[...]
```

or you can put for the not nullable option

```
[Required]
```

in your model propriety and then put an if before the Regex with

```
if(!ModelState.isValid){ [...] }
```

Comment: I'll edit my question - I'm more interested in getting the built-in validation working via data-annotations. (Your code would not help me on the client side, which is where I'm seeing the problem).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to add a JavaScript event listener in your view for either key pressed or key up and bind it to the editor element.

You could then use that event listener to either discard or undo key strokes that are not numbers or related characters like '-', '.' or ',' depending on your localization. You could even put in a little logic so that it only allows '-' if it's the first character.

Comment: the problem with this is that an user can paste inside the input

Comment: I could write my own JavaScript, yes - but surely there must be a way to do this using the existing framework? Since I'm using data-annotations to do other types of validation, it'd be a bit annoying to have to hard-code validation for this one (common!) type of field.